# Can I still travel to HK with a 5 year travel ban from China?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, hong-kong, criminal-records

I was detained and deported from China for a minor offense. The Chinese police authorities said they would not share my record with any other countries and that I would only have a record in China with a 5 year entry ban. I want to go to Hong Kong and have been offered a job, will I still be able to get a work visa in Hong Kong or even just travel there? as I can show that I have a clean criminal record from my home country.
 I am afraid that my passport has been flagged with HK immigration. Usually I am able to enter Hong Kong visa free.

Comment: Does the company that offered you a job know you are subject to a 5 year travel ban in China? Hong Kong is part of China. If they are not aware of it and then find out, your offer may be rescinded. If they are aware of it and don't care they might be able to help by having an immigration attorney make the appropriate consultations before you arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have friends who were deported from Shenzhen after getting a 5 year travel ban, they were allowed to leave China through Hong Kong, and stay in Hong Kong afterwards.

Comment: How reliable is an anecdote from some RIS about friends?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but what is a RIS?

Comment: @JosephP. Random Internet Stranger

Comment: Was this recently, or before Honk Kong was handed back to China?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would contact HK Immigration directly and get a response from them, at a minimum in email. If they say you are good to go, then if you run into issues upon your entry, you can at least reference that email (or whatever documentation they provided). If you do get a response, get the immigration officer's name (or at least try, many times they do not want to provide their ID). Or have someone you know that is in HK go down to immigration and speak to them directly about your situation.